# How to list your cordova app built by Intel XDK in "open with..." menu in Android?

Tags: cordova, intel-xdk

I need to know that my app appears on the open with list of android.

For example:

[image]

I tried with this https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent

but I had no idea how to edit AndroidManifest.xml using Intel XDK, I got no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is build.xml as extension file to allow use of AndroidManifest.xml to add some intents in Intel XDK plugin manager.